# WSO2 DSS return date and time fom Oracle date field

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I have a data service that has to return a dateTime xml field from and Oracle date field.

I have try with

```
<element column="DATE" name="ActionDate" xsdType="xs:dateTime"/>
```

with no success. No time is returned.

I finally format the returned field in the sql to return an xml dateTime this way

```
to_CHAR(DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')||'T'||to_CHAR(DATE, 'hh24:mi:ss')
```

but I do not think this is an smart way to do this.

Does anybody know who to do that using wso2 dss resources instead of concatenation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What are you getting as the output for

```
<element column="DATE" name="ActionDate" xsdType="xs:dateTime"/>
```

? This should work and return date time value.

Comment: Just date value with no time